# IIS-Hosted WCF REST service - JSON serialize enum as string

Tags: c#, json, rest, wcf, enums

Is it possible to serialize the enum as either a proper string value or the value specified by the *EnumMember* attribute rather than a number? It seems that JSON serialization ignores the *Value* property of *EnumMember* attribute. If I change WebMessageFormat to Xml it works fine, but I need to use JSON.

I have the following IIS-Hosted REST Service

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    UriTemplate = "test")]
    SomeObject Test();
```

SomeObject:

```
[DataContract]
public class SomeObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public SomeEnum FooBar
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

SomeEnum:

```
[DataContract]
public enum SomeEnum
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "FooValue")]
    [Description("FooDescription")]
    Foo,

    [EnumMember(Value = "BarValue")]
    [Description("BarDescription")]
    Bar,
}
```

What I get:

```
{"FooBar":0}
```

I'd like to get one of the following (preferably the first, but either one works):

```
{"FooBar": "FooValue"}
{"FooBar": "Foo"}
```

Comment: Hey ! were you able to solve the problem using the approach suggested below ? If not can you please update details and possibly resolution ? If yes can you please upvote and/or mark response below as asnwer ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to reference [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) 
use StringEnumConverter attribute on your property as follows :

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public SomeEnum FooBar {get;set;}
```

Please refer to newtonsoft [docs](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter.htm) for more details
Hope this helps !